# How to specify kernel parameters in Spike (riscv)?

Tags: linux, parameters, kernel, boot, riscv

I want to reserve a portion of physical memory when booting Linux. The common kernel parameters should be like "mem=51M memmap=512M$512M". How can I specify these parameters for kernel for Spike?

My Spike execution commands are :

```
u@ubuntu14.04:~/riscv$ spike -m2048 +disk=./root.bin bbl ./linux-3.14.33/vmlinux
              vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrr       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  
rrrrrrrrrrrrr       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
rr                vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      
rr            vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rr
rrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrr
rrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrr
rrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvv      rrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vv      rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr          rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr  rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

       INSTRUCTION SETS WANT TO BE FREE
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.14.33-g043bb5d (guanglin@guanglin-a11-linux) (gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC) ) #2 Sun Aug 23 17:19:49 EDT 2015
[    0.000000] Detected 0x7fc00000 bytes of physical memory
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x00200000-0x7fdfffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00200000-0x7fdfffff]
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 516110
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: root=/dev/htifblk0
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
[    0.000000] Sorting __ex_table...
[    0.000000] Memory: 2058700K/2093056K available (1722K kernel code, 124K rwdata, 356K rodata, 68K init, 211K bss, 34356K reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:2
[    0.150000] Calibrating delay using timer specific routine.. 20.01 BogoMIPS (lpj=100050)
[    0.150000] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.150000] Mount-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.150000] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.150000] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.150000] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[    0.150000] Switched to clocksource riscv_clocksource
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.150000] TCP established hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.150000] TCP bind hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.150000] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 16384 bind 16384)
[    0.150000] TCP: reno registered
[    0.150000] UDP hash table entries: 1024 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.150000] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 1024 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.150000] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 6144 bytes)
[    0.150000] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.150000] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.150000] htifcon htif1: detected console
[    0.150000] console [htifcon0] enabled
[    0.150000] htifblk htif2: detected disk
[    0.150000] htifblk htif2: added htifblk0
[    0.150000] TCP: cubic registered
[    0.150000] VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) readonly on device 254:0.
[    0.150000] devtmpfs: mounted
[    0.150000] Freeing unused kernel memory: 68K (ffffffff80000000 - ffffffff80011000)
[    0.160000] EXT2-fs (htifblk0): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
/ #
```

I tried

```
spike -m2048 +disk=./root.bin bbl ./linux-3.14.33/vmlinux mem=1G memmap=1G$1G
spike -m2048 +disk=./root.bin bbl ./linux-3.14.33/vmlinux mem=512M memmap=512M$512M
```

None of them works.

If I do

```
spike -m2048 +disk=./root.bin bbl "./linux-3.14.33/vmlinux mem=512M memmap=512M$512M"
```

couldn't open ELF program: ./linux-3.14.33/vmlinux mem=512M memmap=512M12M!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, arguments to linux need to compiled into linux via the CONFIG_CMDLINE parameter in .config.

A future version of bbl could be improved to support passing arguments to linux.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly how I can specify kernel parameters.